# Get information from users when they auto login in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a razor web app and every time someone login, I get the user id and write it at the database.

But if the user enable autologin (remember me), how can I know when someone access the site to do the same thing.

Something like `Session_OnStart` in the old classic ASP.

Any help?

Comment: When some would login it will be redirected to `account login.cshtml.cs ` where you will get `await UserManager.FindByNameAsync("UserName");` which will provide login user information. You can [`check here in official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.findbynameasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: That's true, but if the user enable the option "remenber me" I can't find a way to cacth it.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of research i find a solution.

Adding this to program.cs just before app.Run(); made the trick.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Session.GetInt32("initialized") == null) //check if session?
    {
        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { //check if user is authenticated
            var logVisit = new TabLogVisits()
            {
                Id = context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value,
                LoginDT = DateTime.UtcNow
            };
            using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var _context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                _context.TabLogVisits.Add(logVisit);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); //Regist the visit
            }
        context.Session.SetInt32("initialized", 1); //set session "true"
        }
    }
    await next(context); //run next code

});
```